# shell script: convert raw output (from dict lines into csv)

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Can anyone help me to convert below raw output to `csv` or a `key value pair`.

i have tried `awk`, `sed` methods but the problem is... data{} contains 2 key-value pairs, sometimes it has only one key-value pair like shown in 3rd row. (myID is missing in 3rd row)

```
"data":{"myID":"111" "Country":"United Kingdom"
"data":{"myID":"222" "Country":"Germany"
"data":{"Country":"United Kingdom" "data":{"myID":"444"
"Country":"United Kingdom" "data":{"myID":"555"
"Country":"United Kingdom" "data":{"Country":"United Kingdom"
```

trying to get below output.

```
111,United Kingdom
222,Germany
,United Kingdom
444,United Kingdom
555,United Kingdom
,United Kingdom
```

please help.. thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like mangled json. Do you have the original valid json data?

Comment: @Shawn - this is the API output received from a server & i have filter unwanted lines using `grep` in my shell script. this the output that i have managed to get.

Comment: You should be using a json aware tool like `jq`, not things like grep or sed.

Comment: Where did that 3rd line of output `,United Kingdom` come from? Please [edit] your question to either explain it or fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n"Country":/,/;s/ "data":{/\n/;s/"data":{\|"myID"://g;s/ *"Country":/,/g;s/"//g;P;D' file
```

From the data provided, this sed solution provides the stated format but some how I think that there may be edge cases not accounted for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @potong you saved my time, this worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your data it's best to build an array mapping those tags (aka names or keys) to their values and then you can just print them by name. If you find yourself with data in future that has more tag-value pairs just add the tag names to the string in the first arg to split() and the rest of the script will work as-is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numTags = split("myID Country",tagList)
    for (i in tagList) {
        tags[tagList[i]]
    }
    FS = "\""
    OFS = ","
}
{
    delete tag2val
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
        if ( $i in tags ) {
            tag2val[$i] = $(i+2)
        }
    }
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tagList[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
111,United Kingdom
222,Germany
444,United Kingdom
555,United Kingdom
,United Kingdom
```